# How can I get standard out for an assembly via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

More or less, I am dynamically executing user code, and I would like to capture things like Write and Read methods from console, like a file or command line program would.

Here's what my code looks like for executing a dynamic program with one Main.

```
  _assembly = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly;
  object o = _assembly.CreateInstance(ClassNameString);
  MethodInfo mi = _assembly.EntryPoint;
  mi.Invoke(o, null);
```

Comment: As you're generating the code via the codedom, why not generate the code to send the output where you want it? Had it been a full blown pre-existing EXE, I'd have suggested using the Process class and seetting the appropiate members on the StartInfo property.

Comment: Ok, do you mean including methods print(), read() etc, that use some file, and then reading that file?

Answer (score 1):

An assembly doesn't get a separate output. That's per process.

You'll have to listen to your own standard out or pass a stream into your generated class.

Comment: how do you pass a stream into a generated/compiled class?

Comment: As a parameter to a method or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the reader and writer behind Console.Out and Console.In:

```
Console.SetOut(new MyInterceptingTextWriter());
Console.SetIn(new MyInterceptingReader());

// your code here
```